# Spring validation didn't display error messages saved in property file (freemarker template)

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, javabeans, freemarker

I have a problem with display error message defined in .properties file.

Here is my servlet-context.xml fragment (it should define resource bundle and inject it into validator; the resource messages are working well everywhere else):

```
  <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="pl"/>
  </bean>

  <bean name="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource" />
  </bean>
```

And here is a fragment of my property file:

```
messages.forms.validation.size.between=bla bla bla
messages.forms.validation.size.between.and=and
```

Here is a field definition.

```
@NotEmpty
@NotNull
@Size(min = 4, max = 25, message = "{messages.forms.validation.size.between} {min} {messages.forms.validation.size.between.and} {max}")
private String login;
public void setLogin(String v) { login = v; }
public String getLogin() { return login; }
```

What I expect is (according to: message = "{messages.forms.validation.size.between} {min} {messages.forms.validation.size.between.and} {max}") to get an error:
**bla bla bla 4 and 25**, but instead of it, I'm getting:
[image: not converted message]

I have spent couple of hours trying to find a solution with no success, so please help!

Comment: I see what you are trying to do but can I ask why are you not just simply doing message = "Size must be between 4 and 25" ? not a criticism just interested in why you are using this way ?

Comment: Having all strings in a property file will provide an easy way to make an multi-language application in a future.

Comment: yes but why set the message like that in the bean why not just set it in the properties file? in my bean I just have annotations like @Size and then in properties file Size.userBean.username = Username must be minimum of 6 characters and a maximum of 16 characters. and the message gets displayed on jsp upon validation

Comment: seems nice solution, could you show an example code? I'm using freemarker instead of jsp and I hope it does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write your message within the properties file, there is no need to set the message within the Bean. Below is how I display validation error messages via a properties file.

servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="com.sga.app.messages"></property>
</bean>
```

UserBean.java:

```
@NotBlank
@Size(min = 6, max = 16)
@Pattern(regexp = "^\\w{6,}$")
@Id
private String username;
```

messages.properties:

```
Size.userBean.username = Username must be between 6 and 16 characters in length
```

register.jsp:

```
<li>
    <label id="outputUsername">
    <c:out value="Enter username:"></c:out>
    </label>
    <sf:input class="usernameInput" name="username" type="text"
      path="username" tabindex="0" id="usernameInput" />
    <sf:errors path="username" cssStyle="color:red;
      font-size: small;" />
</li>
```

Comment: nope, this is not working. In your propertis file you have Size.userBean.username - and I have no such thing like an userBean in my freemarker template. I will change title of my question a little. Anyway thanks ! :)

Comment: @Mariusz.v7 userBean is just the name of my Bean Java class that has all my getters/setters/properties and username is the name of the property. like what you currently have for private String login;

Comment: btw is this possible to change message to something like this: Size.userBean.username = Username must be minimum of {min} characters and a maximum of 
{max} characters? (where {min} and {max} are declared in annotation)

Comment: I have just performet quick set of tries. Changed to:  Size.userBean.username = Username must be minimum of {2} characters and a maximum of {1} characters. Try it yourself :)